# How are points awarded in the group stage of the Rugby World Cup?

Tags: rules, rugby-union

After the first matches of the 2015 Rugby World Cup there are:

- winner teams with 5 points
- winner teams with 4 points
- loser teams with 2 points
- loser teams with 1 points
- loser teams with 0 points

How are points awarded for each match?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In common with many of the major domestic leagues, the World Cup is using the concept of "bonus points" in addition to points for a win or draw. The precise details can be seen in section 1.1.2 of the [Tournament Rules](https://web.archive.org/web/20160214132854/https://www.rugbyworldcup.com/tournament-rules):

> The following number of Match points will be awarded for each pool phase Match:
>
> - Win 4 points
> - Draw 2 points
> - Loss 0 points
> - 4 or more tries 1 point
> - Loss by 7 points or less 1 point

Therefore the teams with 5 points both won and scored 4 or more tries; the teams with 4 won, but didn't score 4 tries. The team with 2 points [lost, but both scored 4 or more tries and lost by 7 points or fewer](http://www.rugbyworldcup.com/match/14194#latest). Teams with one point lost, and *either* scored 4 or more tries, or lost by 7 points or fewer. Teams with zero points lost and neither scored 4 tries nor lost by 7 points or fewer.

Comment: I’ll just add that these 1-point additions are called “bonus points” and are usually indicated separately in the group standings tables (e.g. by “BP”). See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rugby_union_bonus_points_system